# Difference b/w Redraw and Scale to Fill Mode in UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, interface-builder, xcode4.2

For an UIImageView, different mode options are given In the interface builder like Aspect Fit, Aspect Fill. Can anyone tell me what is the difference b/w these two modes: **Scale to Fill** VS **Redraw**?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`

For the first time, `drawRect:` is called and view is rendered. Later, when geometry changes, `drawRect:` is not called and already rendered content is scaled to draw the view.

`UIViewContentModeRedraw`

Every time you change bounds, `drawRect:` is called to render the view again, again and again. Unless you know what are you really doing and unless you really need it, don't use it. It's much slower, because it must call `drawRect:` again and again. In other words, when you set `UIViewContentModeRedraw` it's same behavior as when you call `setNeedsDisplay` every time bounds are changed.

Simplified explanation, but should clarify it a bit for you.